# Powershell script to list large files on multiple servers

Tags: powershell

I have been trying to create/modify a Powershell script that allows me to automate finding all files across multiple servers larger than 1GB and excluding .ldf and mdf.

I have found a script, but it only looks into the current C Drive and although I've been trying to modify this, I have been unsuccessful.

I'm unsure how to modify this to fit finding multiple servers.

```
gci -r|sort -descending -property length | select -first 10 name, @{Name="Gigabytes";Expression={[Math]::round($_.length / 1GB, 2)}}
```

Please help.

Comment: how large are the drives? `Get-ChildItem` is _slow_ on large drives. REALLY slow. [*grin*] you can usually get things faster by using Robocopy with the `-L` option to just list the files. ///// for getting info from all the drives, use `Get-PSDrive` to get the drives, filter out the mapped drives & the read-only items [cd, dvd, bluray, card readers], then iterate over that list.

Comment: Yikes. I didn't know it would be really slow. The drives are large but I don't know by how much. I have been using google and saw the PSDrive. I also did not think to remove CD, DVD, and such. Thank you.

Comment: you are most welcome! [*grin*] ///// yep, the slowness can be a real surprise. `Get-ChildItem` is a good bit of code, but it is generalized to handle a bunch of different situations. that leads quite naturally to being rather slow. robocopy is highly optimized for what it does - and getting a listing is a needed part of doing copies. ///// it looks like TurboToast has a good script for you. try it as is to see if it's fast enuf.

Answer (score 4):

**Complete Script:**

```
$size=1GB
$path="C:\"
$omit="*.mdf,*.ldf"
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Exclude $omit -Recurse -OutBuffer 1000|
where {($_.Length -gt $size)}|Select Name, Directory, Length
```

**Sample Output:**

```
Name                                Directory                Length
----                                ---------                ------
CAP2015-07-29 21-07-08-71.avi       C:\                  1216624984
CAP2015-07-29 21-08-17-48.avi       C:\Movies            1205696024
```

**Explination of Script:**

Variable for controlling search size. Can be KB, MB, GB

```
$size=1GB
```

Variable to set base path to search from

```
$path="C:\"
```

Variable to set list of excluded extensions

```
$omit="*.mdf,*.ldf"
```

Searches through all items from the **$Path** recursively and returns only files that are over the set size controlled by **$size**, and omits files listed in **$omit**.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Exclude $omit -Recurse -OutBuffer 1000|
    where {($_.Length -gt $size)}|Select Name, Directory, Length
```

**NOTE:** The **-OutBuffer** parameter controls how many items are gathered before continuing. Managing this parameter correctly can greatly increase the speed with which a command completes. This is from a group of parameter called "CommonParameters". Knowing what these are, and how they work is invaluable.
[Microsoft Docs about_CommonParameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters?view=powershell-6)

Comment: Thank you. I will check this out as well!

Comment: nice code! [*grin*] you may want to add a comment about what the `-OutBuffer` parameter is doing there.